# Edit suggestions are escaping HTML when they shouldn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, timestamps

The "proposed X minutes ago by an anonymous user" text in an edit submission is escaped so it shows HTML:

[image: Screenshot of edit suggestion]

A similar thing happens in titles; [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/234744):

[image: Screenshot of the title diff]

<sub>(At first I thought fencliff had gone mad and added a dozen HTML tags to the title)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issues here, but it's 6 hours later now, things have been reviewed, and the website has been updated to rev 2011.2.16.2 today:

[image: Edit suggestion for title]